# how to use more then one master-slave architecture in Redis

Tags: java, redis, bigdata, imdb

I am using Redis as In Memory Data store. In Redis It is possible to replicate the same data over more then one node with the help of Master-Slave architecture. I use redisson as java client for this architecture and it's working fine. But How can I configure more then one master-slave configuration so that sharding of the keys occur on two nodes and same client is able to fetch the data at which ever node the data exist.

Comment: There are a lot of questions in this one question. You mention sharding in the end which is not a goal of a Maste-Slave architecture. From my understanding Redis does not provide a way to guarantee read distribution on it's own. I use sentinel(http://redis.io/topics/sentinel) for master-slave management and failover. I would take a look at this and see if it fits your use case.

Comment: this is all you need: http://redis.io/topics/replication